# How to see php function parameter with kcachegrind

Tags: php, kcachegrind

i used kcachegrind for see xdebug profile file.

how can i see passed parameters to functions or methods in kcachegrind in cycle

Answer (score 0):

[xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace) has a option to set `xdebug.collect_params` in order to collect the parameters. i didn't try it actually, so i don't know how kcachegrind uses this information.

Comment: This value has no affect on profiling. Seems mostly helpful while viewing PHP warning/error messages—by adjusting this value you can see arguments passed to functions mentioned in stack traces.